# how to recompile apk without any errors?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am not a android developer,

i am working on C# from last 8 years. 
and learning android now.

i want to create a modded app for my personal use.

**i do the same thing before with apktool, but now i import my project into android studio**

I decompile a apk and now want to recompile

i m using android studio for build my project.

i am getting error on these files
AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl.java
BackStackRecord.javaActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb.javai get error on these files and here is my gradle consol output-

```css
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\accessibilityservice\AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl.java:13: error: <identifier> expected
static class  extends 
            ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\accessibilityservice\AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl.java:14: error: illegal start of type
{
^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\accessibilityservice\AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl.java:46: error: illegal start of type
    ()
    ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\accessibilityservice\AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl.java:46: error: ';' expected
    ()
     ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\accessibilityservice\AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl.java:13: error: <identifier> expected
static interface 
                ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$1.java:11: error: <identifier> expected
static class 
            ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImpl.java:13: error: <identifier> expected
private static interface 
                        ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImplBase.java:13: error: <identifier> expected
private static class <init>
                    ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImplBase.java:14: error: illegal start of type
    implements <init>
               ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImplBase.java:15: error: illegal start of expression
{
^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImplBase.java:32: error: illegal start of type
    private ()
            ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImplBase.java:32: error: ';' expected
    private ()
             ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImplBase.java:36: error: illegal start of type
    ( )
    ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImplBase.java:36: error: ';' expected
    ( )
     ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImplHC.java:13: error: <identifier> expected
private static class <init>
                    ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImplHC.java:14: error: illegal start of type
    implements <init>
               ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImplHC.java:15: error: illegal start of expression
{
^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImplHC.java:32: error: illegal start of type
    private ()
            ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImplHC.java:32: error: ';' expected
    private ()
             ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImplHC.java:36: error: illegal start of type
    ( )
    ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImplHC.java:36: error: ';' expected
    ( )
     ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$Delegate.java:12: error: <identifier> expected
public static interface 
                       ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider.java:11: error: <identifier> expected
public static interface 
                       ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider.java:14: error: <identifier> expected
    public abstract  getDrawerToggleDelegate();
                                            ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$SlideDrawable.java:18: error: <identifier> expected
private class <init> extends InsetDrawable
             ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$SlideDrawable.java:19: error: '{' expected
    implements android.graphics.drawable.it>
                                           ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$SlideDrawable.java:74: error: illegal start of type
    private (Drawable drawable)
            ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$SlideDrawable.java:74: error: ';' expected
    private (Drawable drawable)
             ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$SlideDrawable.java:74: error: <identifier> expected
    private (Drawable drawable)
                              ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle$SlideDrawable.java:87: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    mTmpRect(Drawable drawable, mTmpRect mtmprect)
    ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb$SetIndicatorInfo.java:25: error: illegal start of type
    (Activity activity)
    ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb$SetIndicatorInfo.java:25: error: ';' expected
    (Activity activity)
     ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb$SetIndicatorInfo.java:25: error: <identifier> expected
    (Activity activity)
                      ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb$SetIndicatorInfo.java:36: error: not a statement
        nosuchmethodexception;
        ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb$SetIndicatorInfo.java:56: error: illegal start of expression
          goto _L1
          ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb$SetIndicatorInfo.java:56: error: not a statement
          goto _L1
               ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb$SetIndicatorInfo.java:56: error: ';' expected
          goto _L1
                  ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb.java:37: error: not a statement
            nosuchmethodexception;
            ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb.java:57: error: illegal start of expression
              goto _L1
              ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb.java:57: error: not a statement
              goto _L1
                   ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb.java:57: error: ';' expected
              goto _L1
                      ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActivityOptionsCompat$ActivityOptionsImplJB.java:31: error: illegal start of type
    (ActivityOptionsCompatJB activityoptionscompatjb)
    ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActivityOptionsCompat$ActivityOptionsImplJB.java:31: error: ';' expected
    (ActivityOptionsCompatJB activityoptionscompatjb)
     ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\ActivityOptionsCompat$ActivityOptionsImplJB.java:31: error: <identifier> expected
    (ActivityOptionsCompatJB activityoptionscompatjb)
                                                    ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord$Op.java:12: error: <identifier> expected
static final class 
                  ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord$Op.java:19: error: <identifier> expected
     next;
         ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord$Op.java:22: error: <identifier> expected
     prev;
         ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord$Op.java:25: error: illegal start of type
    ()
    ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord$Op.java:25: error: ';' expected
    ()
     ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:321: error: illegal start of expression
        if (op == null) goto _L2; else goto _L1
                        ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:321: error: not a statement
        if (op == null) goto _L2; else goto _L1
                             ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:321: error: illegal start of expression
        if (op == null) goto _L2; else goto _L1
                                       ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:321: error: 'else' without 'if'
        if (op == null) goto _L2; else goto _L1
                                  ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:323: error: not a statement
        op.cmd;
          ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:324: error: ';' expected
        JVM INSTR tableswitch 0 7: default 424
                 ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:324: error: not a statement
        JVM INSTR tableswitch 0 7: default 424
                  ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:324: error: ';' expected
        JVM INSTR tableswitch 0 7: default 424
                             ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:324: error: orphaned default
        JVM INSTR tableswitch 0 7: default 424
                                   ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:324: error: : expected
        JVM INSTR tableswitch 0 7: default 424
                                          ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:324: error: not a statement
        JVM INSTR tableswitch 0 7: default 424
                                           ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:324: error: ';' expected
        JVM INSTR tableswitch 0 7: default 424
                                              ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:333: error: ';' expected
           goto _L3 _L4 _L5 _L6 _L7 _L8 _L9 _L10 _L11
                       ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:333: error: ';' expected
           goto _L3 _L4 _L5 _L6 _L7 _L8 _L9 _L10 _L11
                               ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:333: error: ';' expected
           goto _L3 _L4 _L5 _L6 _L7 _L8 _L9 _L10 _L11
                                       ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:333: error: ';' expected
           goto _L3 _L4 _L5 _L6 _L7 _L8 _L9 _L10 _L11
                                                ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:334: error: ';' expected
_L11:
    ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:337: error: not a statement
        String s1 = (new StringBuilder()).append("cmd=").append(op.cmd).toString();
        ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:337: error: ';' expected
        String s1 = (new StringBuilder()).append("cmd=").append(op.cmd).toString();
              ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:392: error: illegal start of expression
          goto _L12
          ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:393: error: ';' expected
_L5:
   ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:395: error: illegal start of expression
          goto _L12
          ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:396: error: ';' expected
_L6:
   ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:398: error: illegal start of expression
          goto _L12
          ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:399: error: ';' expected
_L7:
   ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:401: error: illegal start of expression
          goto _L12
          ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:402: error: ';' expected
_L8:
   ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:404: error: illegal start of expression
          goto _L12
          ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:405: error: ';' expected
_L9:
   ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:407: error: illegal start of expression
          goto _L12
          ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:408: error: ';' expected
_L10:
    ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:410: error: illegal start of expression
          goto _L12
          ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:412: error: illegal start of expression
          goto _L12
          ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:415: error: illegal start of expression
          goto _L13
          ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:416: error: ';' expected
_L2:
   ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:505: error: not a statement
        op.cmd;
          ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:506: error: ';' expected
        JVM INSTR tableswitch 1 7: default 116
                 ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:506: error: not a statement
        JVM INSTR tableswitch 1 7: default 116
                  ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:506: error: ';' expected
        JVM INSTR tableswitch 1 7: default 116
                             ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:506: error: orphaned default
        JVM INSTR tableswitch 1 7: default 116
                                   ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:506: error: : expected
        JVM INSTR tableswitch 1 7: default 116
                                          ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:506: error: not a statement
        JVM INSTR tableswitch 1 7: default 116
                                           ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:506: error: ';' expected
        JVM INSTR tableswitch 1 7: default 116
                                              ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:514: error: ';' expected
           goto _L1 _L2 _L3 _L4 _L5 _L6 _L7 _L8
                       ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:514: error: ';' expected
           goto _L1 _L2 _L3 _L4 _L5 _L6 _L7 _L8
                               ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:514: error: ';' expected
           goto _L1 _L2 _L3 _L4 _L5 _L6 _L7 _L8
                                       ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:514: error: ';' expected
           goto _L1 _L2 _L3 _L4 _L5 _L6 _L7 _L8
                                               ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:522: error: not a statement
        Fragment fragment = op.fragment;
        ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:522: error: ';' expected
        Fragment fragment = op.fragment;
                ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:527: error: illegal start of expression
        if (true) goto _L10; else goto _L9
                  ^
C:\Users\praveen\workspace\Myapp\src\android\support\v4\app\BackStackRecord.java:527: error: not a statement
        if (true) goto _L10; else goto _L9
                       ^
100 errors

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13.394 secs
```

**how to solve these errors**

Comment: This is support-v4 guts. Not very nicely decompiled obviously. Why dont you import this library as maven dependency?

Comment: This is android studio 101. Try creating an empty project in AS and read both build.gradle files for clues.